# Retrive specific deleted nodes and re-import

Tags: 7, database

Some nodes (from two different CTs) have been deleted accidentally and there is [no way](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/645/is-it-possible-to-restore-a-deleted-node) to restore them.

The question: is it possible to retrieve and import these very specific deleted nodes from our backups without making a full database restore, and having the reassembled nodes back to the UI, is there any method/technique that will work ?

One of our CTs consists of many many fields (~80) of any possible type image, link, entity/taxonomy reference, integer, text, file and Boolean.

I have already looked at the [Node export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) but it depends on the [uuid](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid) module and I don't have that installed.

Answer (score 2):

We had this same problem on one of our sites and the best solution we could come up with was to use [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) as you mentioned. Like you, we didn't have it or [UUID](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid) installed at that time, but we installed them just for this purpose, and it worked fine.

The only catch is you need to be able to load the backed-up database into a functioning site (we did it on our test server) before you can export the missing nodes.